# How to create the custom locator in selenium recorder for firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to create a custom locator in the Selenium recorder so that i can get the parameters as per my requirements.

Comment: a properties file shall help, where in a replica of an hashmap could help with keys being the access type and values as defined